# Multi color on font awesome icon with css

Tags: css, font-awesome

I had upgraded my rating plugin with font awesome icons instead of images. I am facing problem on half star rated which I can't replace white color on the fa-star-half-o icon. I would like to replace the white color with grey color similar to expected result below.

Please help

Code :

```
<div class="ratingbox"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star">
</i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star unrated"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star enlang unrated"></i></div>
```

```css
i
{
  float:left
}
.ratingbox
{
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.fa-star-half-o,.fa-star
{
    color: #ffab00;
  
}
.rated{
    color: #ffab00;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.unrated{
    color: #757575;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ratingbox">
<i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star unrated"></i><i class="fa fa-star enlang unrated"></i>
</div>
```

Current Result

[image]

Expected Result

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is possible in web design but maybe you manage to use some trick:

```css
i
{
  float:left;
  position: relative;
}
.ratingbox
{
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.fa-star-half-o,.fa-star
{
    color: #ffab00;
  
}
.rated{
    color: #ffab00;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.unrated{
    color: #757575;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-star-half-empty:after, .fa-star-half-full:after, .fa-star-half-o:after {
    content: "\f123";
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    display: inline-block;
    left: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    color: #757575;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ratingbox">
<i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star unrated"></i><i class="fa fa-star enlang unrated"></i>
</div>
```

Note: I just add `fa-star-half-o` character to `after` element, i mean this `content: "\f123";` then reverse it `transform: rotateY(-180deg);` and half width and absolute position you can see what's happened here:

```
.fa-star-half-empty:after, .fa-star-half-full:after, .fa-star-half-o:after {
    content: "\f123";
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    display: inline-block;
    left: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    color: #757575;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 8px;
}
```

It's not clean but better than nothing!

Comment: `::after`, not `:after`. `:after` is deprecated CSS2 syntax.

Comment: "Everything is possible in web design." Thank you for the positive attitude, @Pedram.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements refer [here](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/) for CSS unicodes.

1. Add an extra `.unrated` star
2. Add 2 pseudo-elements to the `half-o` ; `::before` and `::after`
3. Make sure that the pseudo-elements are absolute and the `half-o` is relative.
4. And to cleanly fill the rightside of half star, explicitly set the `::before` pseudo-element to `color:grey`.

### Demo

```css
i {
  float: left;
}

.ratingbox {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.fa-star-half-o,
.fa-star {
  color: #ffab00;
}

.rated {
  color: #ffab00;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.unrated {
  color: #757575;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-star-half-o {
  position: relative;
}


.fa-star-half-o:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f089';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fa-star-half-o:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f089';
  position: absolute;
  color: grey;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ratingbox">
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star unrated"></i><i class="fa fa-star unrated"></i><i class="fa fa-star unrated"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there's a missing semi colon near float: left

Comment: @NigelFds Hi thanks for the heads up, but the semi-colon isn't needed for the last property of a CSS rule set. The semi-colon is actually removed at the end by minimizers. Regardless, I'll add it for consistency's sake, thanks again.